# Display Status of various services on a server from Nagios on a public web page

Tags: nagios

I want display the status of various services on a server from Nagios on a public web page.

Is it possible?

Comment: yes, you can integrate the nagios page iframes into your public web page.

Comment: I want to Display only the list of services and their status...Not the whole page...Is it possible

Comment: `Is it possible` - Yes.  There are various alternate front ends other then the CGI that provide a lot more flexibility.  You could create a front end that interfaces with livestatus or something and pulls the data you want and displays it.  There are lots of options.

Comment: Can you please provide an example...

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to write some code to pull and display the status information you're interested in.

Nagios 4 has a built-in [JSON API](https://labs.nagios.com/tag/json-cgi/).

Previous versions required an add-on. There are a variety of [API add-ons](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/APIs/JSON) to expose status information in JSON, XML, etc.